# Get permission to read any char (byte) in C program in VSC

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-code, permissions, memory-address

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *address = (char*)0x004452FC;
    volatile char value;
    printf("Test 1");

    while (1) {
        value = *address;
        printf("Test 2");
        if (value == 1) {
            printf("Test 3");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I run this code, I never reach "Test 2" and it gives me the exitcode 322122547. I am running the program in VSC but it also didn't work in cmd with administrator permissions. The address is from a .exe game I am running and it is the number of a stage I am currently in.

Comment: For starters add a newline and a `fflush(stdout)` to each `printf`. Without that terminal debugging is hopeless.

Comment: Are you *sure* the error isn't `3221225477` which is `0xC0000005` illegal memory access? BTW you can't expect admin privileges to enable access to hard coded memory locations. How do you expect that address to relate to the game anyway? Executables work in virtual memory.

Comment: Accessing that address in your own process will not access that address in a game running in a separate process. Address spaces are virtualized; each process has its own address space that is separate from others, except for special places mapped to shared memory.

Comment: Unless this thread is running in the game memory space, you're most likely going to crash since you have no idea if the address is valid. Also you typically need to read privileges on the memory page.

Comment: are you trying to "tap in" to another process' memory space from one of your own? Not that simple at all for all the reasons mentioned. You'll surely need to get down into the kernel to do such a thing.

Comment: Even if you could access the memory space of the running program, what makes you think the address given is the one you want to access?  It's quite low, and Windows DLLs and dynamic executables can be and are loaded at varying addresses.  `0x004452FC` looks to me more like an *offset* than an absolute address.

Comment: JoniKauf, Tip: report the return value in hexadecimal.  Often that is illuminating.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I got it from cheat engine! I basically use the address already for a livesplit asl file, so an autosplitter that splits whenever the number on the address changes.

Comment: @WeatherVane 
I get this output:


*  Task wird ausgeführt: C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /d /c .\build\Debug\outDebug.exe 

Test 1
 *  Der Terminalprozess "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe '/d', '/c', '.\build\Debug\outDebug.exe'" wurde mit folgendem Exitcode beendet: 3221225477. 
 *  Das Terminal wird von Aufgaben wiederverwendet, drücken Sie zum Schließen eine beliebige Taste.

Comment: That's what I guessed, but the question says 322122547.

Comment: if you're on windows you should look into [OpenProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) and [ReadProcessMemory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) WinAPI functions to read from a different process. Otherwise you're just trying to access some random address in your own virtual address space. I'd recommend reading up on [virtual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) ;)

Comment: Also you (usually) can't be sure that an address of something remains the same in-between restarts of the target process (game), due to ASLR (address space layout randomization) and non-deterministic heap allocations by the game (`malloc()` is probably not going to return the same virtual addresses for your target object in the game every time). For that you need to find a "pointer path" (a chain of pointers and offsets) relative to the base address of the target process. Tools like Cheat Engine can be a great help with that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't read from or write data to this memory address is that every process on Linux/Windows/macOS has its own [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) address space. This means that a memory address like `0x004452FC` does not refer to an address in your physical memory, it is only virtual. Before the CPU can access the data from a virtual memory address, it must first translate it to a physical address using a page table.

Since these page tables are process-specific, the same virtual address in two processes will most likely belong to two different physical addresses. These page tables are managed by the operating system, and you can't really look up the physical address of an entry, nor would the operating system allow you to read/write to physical addresses directly (with the exception of kernel drivers). Before you can use a memory address (or more accurately, a page of memory), you must ask the operating system to create a mapping for that virtual memory address. Since you didn't ask for a mapping for `0x004452FC`, you tried to access non-existent memory and the OS killed your process.

If you want to change the memory contents of other processes, you must use special APIs provided by the operating system. On Windows this would be [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory)/[WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory), on Linux you need to use [ptrace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) and for macOS you need [vm_read](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1585350-vm_read)/[vm_write](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1585462-vm_write).

Comment: TYSM! This helped a lot!